# i am writing the below mentioned simple code in python, but it does not open

Tags: python

I am writing the below mentioned simple code in python, but it does not open the file(list1.txt), I am using IDLE 3.7.0. When I write the code without the first line it works! What is the problem?

```py
def list_from_file(a="list1.txt"):
    file_pointer = open("a", 'r')
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    print(data)
```

Comment: Did you *call* the function? Also, the function is opening a file named "a". Not a file named "list1.txt".

Comment: You are defining a function. The second step is to call this function in the main program. The main program is the program executed, i.e. without indentation (false, but good to begin with I guess...). Thus, to read the file, you should do this: `list_from_file("list1.txt")`. Note that you didn't need to put `a="list1.txt"`, you could have simply put `a` as the parameter of your function. Doing `a="list1.txt"` means that the parameter `a` has a default value, and thus `list_from_file()` where `a` is not define will also work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the first line `def list_from_file(a="list1.txt"):` defines a function, everything below and indented (your next 3 lines in this case) belongs to it.

Basically it is a bloc of code in the main program that is only executed if you *call* it. It you don't it will not execute.

To call a function you have to add a line like this:

```
def list_from_file(a="list1.txt"):
    file_pointer = open(a, 'r')
    data = file_pointer.readlines()
    print(data)

list_from_file()
```

Notice how the *call* is on the same indentation level as the first line, this means that this line does not belong to the function itself and thus will be executed.

Also your function have an optional argument `a="list1.txt"` Meaning that you can call your function with another file if you want it by calling it that way: `list_from_file(a="another_list.txt")`, doing so will ignore the default value you put in the function and use the one you gave during the call.

---

I can also notice something strange, you are storing the file you want to open inside the variable `a` (see your first line), but on the second line you are opening a file which name is "a", you are not opening the good file, if you want to open the file "list1.txt" you need to change the second line to:

```
file_pointer = open(a, 'r')  # I removed the quotes around the a to use the variable with the filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_from_file(a="list1.txt"):
  file_pointer = open(a, 'r')
  data = file_pointer.readlines()
  print(data)
```

Remove double quotes or else it takes as string value  as a not file name